# johnny sortable plugin: How to serialize only one list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have three **sortable**  lists. These lists are sortable width [the jhonny sortable plugin](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/). After sorting (onDrop), I just need the sort-data of **the one** list, not of all lists.

```
<ol class="sortable">
  <li data-id="1">Item I</li>
  <li data-id="2">Item II</li>
  <li data-id="3">Item III</li>
</ol>
<ol class="sortable">
  <li data-id="37">Item A</li>
  <li data-id="12">Item B</li>
  <li data-id="19">Item C</li>
</ol>
<ol class="sortable">
  <li data-id="21">Item One</li>
  <li data-id="22">Item Two</li>
  <li data-id="20">Item Three</li>
</ol>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var sort = $("sortable").sortable({
    onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {

    var order = sort.sortable("serialize").get(); 

    // order contains the values of ALL lists
    // shuld only contain the values of the ONE list!

  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var order = item.parent().sortable("serialize").get();
```